temporary variable in list comprehension
Is there a concise way to rewrite the following code fragment as a list comprehension?
nsms = []
for line in lines:
    fields = line.split(';')
    if len(fields) > 4 and fields[4] == 'NSM':
        nsms += [fields]

The challenge is the temporary variable fields.  Without it, the comprehension must call split (up to) three times per line:
nsms = [line.split(';')
    for line in lines
    if len(line.split(';')) > 4 and line.split(';')[4] == 'NSM']

I'm not worried about the inefficiency of the redundant calls but about their impact on the expressiveness of the code and the increased risk of a typo.
I thought that perhaps with could help:
# My failed attempt
nsms = [fields 
    for line in lines
    with fields = line.split(';')
    if len(fields) > 4 and fields[4] == 'NSM']

(I found it rather surprising that this fails with an indentation error.  My other attempts resulting in a syntax error pointed at the with.)
As far as I can tell, a for loop is the only way to introduce a local temporary into a list comprehension, so a possible hack would be to "iterate" through a list of one item like this:
nsms = [fields
    for line in lines
    for fields in [line.split(';')]
    if len(fields) > 4 and fields[4] == 'NSM']

This works, but is there a way to do it without disguising the temporary as a loop induction variable?

In the above examples, lines is a list of the lines from a text file that contains semicolon-separated values.  Specifically, from a copy of UnicodeData.txt:
with open('UnicodeData.txt', 'r') as source:
    lines = source.readlines()


have you tried using the walrus operator?

Yeah, that could be written as [fields for line in lines if len(fields := line.split(';')) > 4 and fields[4] == 'NSM']

Seems like it would be easier to actually parse it as semicolon-separated values, though; just iterate over a csv.reader and then you get fields directly instead of a line: [fields for fields in csv.reader(source, delimiter=";") if len(fields) > 4 and fields[4] == "NSM"].

Aside: nsms += [fields] is usually written as nsms.append(fields)

Having misinterpreted this myself, an example of input and output might be helpful.

Thanks, I was not aware of the walrus operator.  I think that's the answer.

Yes, a proper csv reader could be useful to solve this particular problem, but I was trying to understand the more general issue of needing a name for a subexpression in a list comprehension.

there's no prize for maximum use of list comprehensions. Your original for loop is more readable than the list comprehension in the answer, IMHO. Use comprehensions when they make things easier, not for their own sake.

@Barmar:  I recognize that a list comprehension may not be the ideal choice for this particular problem.  I was using it as a motivating example for wanting to name a subexpression in a list comprehension.

The walrus operator is likely to be the general solution to that. But I think any list comprehension that needs this shouldn't be a list comprehension.

Yep, this is absolutely a duplicate.  Sorry about that.  I'm surprised I didn't find the original when I was searching nor did I see it in the "Similar Questions" section while I was composing it.

This will work:
nsms = [fields for fields in (line.split(';') for line in lines)
        if len(fields) > 4 and fields[4] == 'NSM']

It uses a generator to perform the split operations, then iterates over the result in a list comprehension.

Clever, but it still makes the operation look like nested loops which is what I didn't like about my own attempt to do that.

This is one of the motivations for adding the assignment operator (:=) to Python.
nsms = [fields for line in lines if len((fields := line.split(';')) > 4 and fields[4] == 'NSM']

You capture the value of lines.split(';') the first time it's used, and reuse the name fields as needed.

Be aware that using the walrus operator means that if there is an existing fields variable outside of the list comprehension, it will be overwritten.

It's easy enough to choose a unique name, so I'd phrase it as "be aware that fields will still be in scope after the list comprehension is evaluated".
